# Set element show and bind event to this element

Tags: jquery

I have this example code

```
$('#element').on('click', function() {
  $('#show').show();
  $('#show').on('keyup', function() {
    // do something
  });
});
```

I think, could I bind the `#show` click event with `show()`? So, I try this.

```
$('#element').on('click', function() {
  $('#show').show().on('keyup', function() {
    // do something
  });
});
```

This not work. I know I can bind the `#show` event before `#element` or after.

My question is could I bind `keyup` event with `show()`?

I have ready jquery document and google, but I still have no idea. Thanks.

Comment: you want to call the click event for show?

Comment: Yes. I want set this element show and bind a event

Comment: `$('#show').show()` returns the jQuery element self, you could chain it like what you did.

Comment: it should be fine... only problem is if you click on element multiple times the keyup handler might get triggered multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two separate handler here:

```
$('#element').on('click', function() {
    $('#show').show();
});

$('#show').on('keyup', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I key wrong, the `#show` bind `keyup` not `click`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use like this,

```
$('#element').on('click', function () {
$('#show').show();
$(document).on('keyup', '#show',function () {
    // do something
});

});
```

If you want to trigger the click, Use `$("show").trigger("click");` for that

Answer (score 0):

It could be easi for you if you will use different Jquery methods as different Modules as::

this is the HTML code as::

```
    <button>Click</button>
    <div id="show">
        <p>Test Paragraph</p>
    </div>
```

and your Jquery code should be something like::

```
$('#show').hide();  
$('#show').on('keyup', function() {
    alert("Keyup!!!");
  });
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('#show').show().keyup();
});
```

for your better understanding just have a look at example::
http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/c7Aqq/